# Javascript reduce shorthand not returning object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Why would one work and the other not ?

```
const b = {
  age: 20,
  name: "John Doe"
}

const sortedB = Object.entries(b).sort().reduce((acc, [key, val]) => acc[key] = val,{});
```

Output: John Doe

The top is leaving out the block brackets which says return acc automatically . 
The bottom is saying use the block braces which means you have to manually return acc

```
  const sortedB = Object.entries(b).sort().reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
    acc[key] = val;
    return acc;
  },{});
```

Output: {age: 20, name: "John Doe"}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The top is leaving out the block brackets which says return acc automatically

No, that's not what it means. How/why should JavaScript know to return `acc`?

If you have an arrow function with only an expression as a body, then the result of that expression is returned. And the result of an assignment is the value that was assigned. Example:

```js
var func = () => 1;
console.log(func()); // 1

func = x => x;
console.log(func(42)) // 42

func = (x, y) => y = 42;
console.log(func(1,2)); // 42

func = x => (x, 42);
console.log(func(21)); // 42

func = x => (42, x);
console.log(func(21)); // 21
```

If you want the value of `acc` returned then you have to make sure the expression evaluates to that value, e.g. with the comma operator:

```
 (acc, [key, val]) => (acc[key] = val, acc)
 //                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 //  the comma operator returns the result of the right expression
```

Comment: This is a clever use case for the comma operator, thank you! What do you think about code readability when using it?

Comment: Good question. I think the comma operator is one of those things that is not commonly used and thus fewer people may know about it and how it works. From that perspective, readability probably suffers.

Answer (score 2):

As it's already explained in another answer, there's no way how `acc[key] = val` expression can *return acc automatically*, because it evaluates to `val`, not `acc`.

A recipe that can be conveniently used in `reduce` function in ES6 is `Object.assign` because it returns an object it extends:

```
Object.entries(b).sort().reduce((acc, [key, val]) => Object.assign(acc, { [key]: val }) ,{});
```

It's more costly than `acc[key] = val; return acc` but can be used in non-critical places (in performance-critical places `Object.entries` and `reduce` aren't welcome, too) and can be used with implied arrow return.

Answer (score 0):

You can use even short version with `ES6`:

```
Object.entries(b).sort().reduce((acc, [key, val]) => ({ ...acc, ...{ [key]: val } }),{});
```